# How to calculate growth in percentage between rows in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data-frame such as:

```
 A   B(int64)
 1   100
 2   150
 3   200
```

now I need to calculate the growth rate and set it as an additional column such as:

```
 A    C
 1   naN
 2   50%
 3  33.33%
```

how can I achieve that? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Yo can compute the growth percentage using the formula you seem to know. Store this into an array 'growth', then add the column to your dataframe `df['C'] = growth`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.pct_change`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.pct_change.html) with multiple by `100` with [`Series.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html) and rounding by [`Series.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html):

```
df['C'] = df.B.pct_change().mul(100).round(2)
print (df)
   A    B      C
0  1  100    NaN
1  2  150  50.00
2  3  200  33.33
```

For percentage add `map` with `format` and processing with missing values with `NaN != NaN`:

```
df['C'] = df.B.pct_change().mul(100).round(2).map(lambda x: '{0:g}%'.format(x) if x==x else x)
print (df)
   A    B       C
0  1  100     NaN
1  2  150     50%
2  3  200  33.33%
```

Comment: This `pct_change()` looks so magical. I would have never guessed it could exist !